# Reg Exp - preg_match_all reduce array result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This is my Reg Exp "[c]?[\d+|\D+]\s*". My input is this "c7=c4/c5*100" and the result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => c7
            [1] => =
            [2] => c5
            [3] => +
            [4] => c3
            [5] => *
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
        )
)
```

But what I want is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => c7
            [1] => =
            [2] => c5
            [3] => +
            [4] => c3
            [5] => *
            [6] => 100
        )

)
```

I can't seem to get the last part working, I'm lost as what to do next - Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\d+|\D+]` which would match any of the specified characters. I think you meant using an or `|` with a [grouping](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) construct `c?(?:\d+|\D+)\s*` but in that case it would match c followed by either `\d+` or `\D` so that would match the `=` sign right after it resulting in `c=` as a match and `/c` as a match.

Try matching an optional c `c?` followed by one or more digits or `|` match not a digit `\D`

[`c?\d+|\D`](https://regex101.com/r/qVnIap/1)

```
$re = '/c?\d+|\D/m';
$str = 'c7=c4/c5*100';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

That will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => c7
            [1] => =
            [2] => c4
            [3] => /
            [4] => c5
            [5] => *
            [6] => 100
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PD9os)